# How To Lock A Channel Using Discord.py Bot

Tags: discord.py

What I need is a bot that can lock a channel on a simple command. For example, when someone says Lock, the bot turns "no message sending" on. Here's what I have so far:

```
@commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
    async def lockdown(self, ctx, message, channel, member):
        if message.author.id == 767435817034842172 and message.content.startswith('Lock Channel Test'):
          overwrite = discord.PermissionOverwrite()
          overwrite.send_messages = False
          overwrite.read_messages = True
          await channel.set_permissions(member, overwrite=overwrite)
          await message.channel.send('**Channel Locked.**\n\n**Reason:** Guild Save Used\n`Please Wait For An Admin/Moderator To Unlock This Channel`')
```

When I do this, all sorts of errors come up. (I'm new to coding)

Can someone please help me? All I've found so far are examples showing just a single part of the matter, and no indication of how to attach a command to it. Please shows me the entire thing, from how to make it respond to a **player command** and the things I need to **import**. Thanks so, so much!

Comment: What are the errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are new and don't really know how to create commands. Well, my advice is you should do such big projects when you are new as they may confuse you and deviate you from the language. Rather should start with simple projects like, Roll the Dice game or Calculator.

But well, now as you have started it let's me show you how to create a bot first. So I am going to tell you on how to create a discord bot using **Commands API**.

We will be going over how to create a prefix for your bot, as most bots that you have probably interacted with have some form of prefix `(e.g. $ or !)`. After that, we will be covering how to create new commands. Finally, we will be going over the built-in help command for the list of commands that your bot has so that you don’t have to create your own.

### Creating your Bot's Prefix.

I am starting from scratch, but if you already have a file with other code you can use it.
So I created a file and added the code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

bot.run("YOU MAY ENTER YOUR BOT'S TOKEN HERE")
```

You need to focus of the line: `bot = command.Bot(command_prefix='!')` as it is of great importance in your code. I assume you have been using the `discord.Client` in order to run your bot but now it is a time for upgrade and a better bot.

#### Defining your Bot's Commands.

Now as we have made a `Bot` object for us, we can go ahead and start making some commands for our bot. The clarity and loveliness of the `Commands API` command are that they are made with just a decorator on the top so that we can easily abstract them.

Let's make a simple `ping-pong` command for us so that you can understand them.

```
@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.send("pong...")
```

Firstly, notice that how we have added the decorator, `@bot.command()` at the top of the function. `bot` is the name of the variable we defined above and `command()` lets the bot know that this is specifically a command.

So, now go the any channel where the bot can send message and then use the command `!ping` and the bot will send a message `pong...`. You can try it.

[image: Command Test 1]

#### Allowing your Bot is Accept Arguments.

Now that we have made a simple command for our bot, what if we want a command who is invoked by a user should include an argument? For instance, what if you want to ping someone who is on the server? It is pretty simple to do that and can be done in many different ways. We'll talk about the simplest one.

```
@bot.command()
async def print(ctx, arg):
    await ctx.channel.send(arg)
```

What will it do? So when the user will execute a command, such as: `!print apples` the bot will consider the word `apples` as `arg` in the command and then send it in the channel the command was executed.

[image: Arg Command]

What if you want to add multiple arguments? Then what? It is simple too. This can be done by changing the function's defining line to:

```
async def print(ctx, *, arg):
```

Now everything after the `!print` command will be considered as `arg` and will be displayed.

[image: Multiple Arg Command]

#### Using In-Built Help Command.

We have basically covered everything we need to develop a bot, but there is one more thing which needs to be highlighted. Now I will mention the pre-built help command of the package.

[image: Help Command 1]

As you can see that now can't see any text about the command besides the, while the `help` have one. We will now let you add text for the command which can be done using some attributes in `command()` discrminator.

```
@bot.command(
    help="Uses come crazy logic to determine if pong is actually the correct value or not.",
    brief="Prints pong back to the channel."
)
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.send("pong")

@bot.command(
    help="Looks like you need some help.",
    brief="Prints the list of values back to the channel."
)
async def print(ctx, *, arg):
    await ctx.channel.send(arg)
```

Now this will add the text we need to the `help` command of our bot. Here the `brief` act as the quick show text of the command when all commands are visible in the bot's message.

Here is how the execution will look like:
[image: Help Modified]

---

This was all you really need to know about the `Commands API`. You can learn more on various other websites. I will add the link of them below.

- Reference- https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-make-discord-bot-commands-in-python-2cae39cbfd55

#### Sites which can be used for learning `Command API` in `discord.py`:

- discordpy.readthedocs.io - https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html
- betterprogramming.pub - The Reference Link
- realpython.com - https://realpython.com/how-to-make-a-discord-bot-python/#using-bot-commands

Hope I was able to make you understand it. Please ask in the comments for any doubts. :)

Thank You! :D

Comment: Thank you so much! For some reason I just couldn't get the async def (ctx) part before you showed me! Thanks so, so much.

Comment: @Coder999 You are very welcome! :D Mind accepting this answer as it helped you out. :D